# C# Code first foreign key. The foreign key refers to the non valid column in table with references

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

I'm creating a `code first` project.

I have some entities, the "incriminated" ones are the following:

**City**

```
public class City
{
    [Key]
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CAP { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ProvinceId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProvinceId")]
    public virtual Province Province { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Shop> Shops { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Street> Streets { get; set; }
}
```

**Province**

```
public class Province
{
    [Key]
    public int ProvinceId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Tag { get; set; }

    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RegionId")]
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

*I have others entities but they are not in the log problem, so I avoided posting them, if those are needed I will add.*

Now, I succesfully did the `Add-Migration name` code.

The problem is in the `Update-Database -verbose` (I added the -verbose way to have an output)

This is the relevant sql code from the -verbose:

**[...]**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cities] (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [CAP] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ProvinceId] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Cities] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)
CREATE INDEX [IX_ProvinceId] ON [dbo].[Cities]([ProvinceId])
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Provinces] (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Tag] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [RegionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Provinces] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)
```

**[...]**

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cities] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Cities_dbo.Provinces_ProvinceId] FOREIGN KEY ([ProvinceId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Provinces] ([ProvinceId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

and now there is the error:

> The external key 'FK_dbo.Cities_dbo.Provinces_ProvinceId' refers the invalid column 'ProvinceId' in table with references 'dbo.Provinces'. Impossible to create the relation, see previous errors

(I manually translated, it might not be perfect)

**LOG:**

**[same error as above]**

```
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass30.<ExecuteStatements>b__2e()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
```

I checked every single solution I found but noone solved my problem. I changed the foreign key, the name of it and the position of it. also the Id names of my tables but nothing..

What am I doing wrong?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You seem to have some data annotations/fluent setup/convention not shown there, because the PK of the both tables are named `Id` (not `ProvinceId` and `CityId` as expected by the above model) in the corresponding database tables.

Comment: @IvanStoev you know I didn't notice it.. Probably I have to delete the initial migration and make the code replace it with a new one

Comment: @IvanStoev that was it.. I used Add-Migration name -Force and now it works. such an easy problem and such a long time to solve it! if you post an answer I will flag it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `Update-Database` log, one can notice that the PK of both tables are named `Id` (rather than `ProvinceId` and `CityId` implied by the model):

> [**Id**] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,

That's why the foreign key constraint reports invalid column name `dbo.Provinces.ProvinceId`.

So there must be some out of sync problem between the model and the generated migration.